# Creating a "pop out window" for user login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I've searched stackoverflow as well as google and can't seem to find a specific enough answer, so I thought I would go ahead and ask it myself!

To provide some background: I am a fairly new rails developer and I've just created a basic app albeit it is lacking some wanted functionality. So far I have integrated Devise, and Omniauth for user login. However, I'd like to have a "pop out window" when users click 'Login' instead of being re-directed to an actual Login page.

If you click on the login button on this website you will see what I am referring to: http://geckodesigns.kinja.com/so-i-bought-a-firetruck-252516685

What sort of Ruby or perhaps Java code would one have to use to implement such functionality?

I look forward to reading your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like `jQuery UI Dialog` for this.

Here's the website for [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). There's also a Rails gem that wraps this library and makes it quite easy to put in your project. You can find that gem on github [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails).

Comment: Note that the website you linked to (geckodesigns) uses a dialog - not a separate popup window.

Comment: Did you mean to post that on the OP's question?

Comment: Right, but I was trying to figure out where I linked to geckodesigns? You stated that I did in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a login page: `html/login.html`

In original page:

```
<a onclick='popupLoginWindow'>Login</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function popupLoginWindow(){
    window.open('html/login.html');
}
```